# How can I set the scroll position relative to the click event and the initial scroll after resizing the inner div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div of 500/500 and overflow:scroll. Another div inside the parent will initially have 1500/1500. After being clicked, the inner div will become 2000/2000.

I need to set the scroll position of the parent div in such way that when after being transformed, it will be scrolled into the view, relative to coordinates of the click event.

I need this for a click to zoom interaction.

```
<div id="parent" style="width:500px; height:500px; overflow: scroll; background-color:red;">
<div id="inner" style="width:1500px; height:1500px;background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it after some headaches:

```
parent.scrollLeft = (clientX + parent.scrollLeft ) * ratio - clientX;
parent.scrollTop = (clientY + parent.scrollTop ) * ratio - clientY;
```